# Open file with two columns and dynamically create variables

Tags: bash, shell

I'm wondering if anyone can help. I've not managed to find much in the way of examples and I'm not sure where to start coding wise either.

I have a file with the following contents...

```
VarA=/path/to/a
VarB=/path/to/b
VarC=/path/to/c
VarD=description of program
...
```

The columns are delimited by the '=' and some of the items in the 2nd column may contain gaps as they aren't just paths.

Ideally I'd love to open this in my script once and store the first column as the variable and the second as the value, for example...

```
echo $VarA
...
/path/to/a


echo $VarB
...
/path/to/a
```

Is this possible or am I living in a fairy land?

Thanks

Comment: `source` comes to mind... Can you show a full example?

Comment: Can you have space or other special chars before `=` as well?

Comment: No spaces, but special characters maybe, but unlikely. It may have an understore or minus in it, but nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the following loop:

```
while IFS== read -r name value; do
    declare "$name=$value"
done < file.txt
```

Note, though, that a line like `foo="3 5"` would include the quotes in the value of the variable `foo`.

Comment: Thank you, I used this with an IF statement before the delare to ignore lines I didn't need (like comments -- or comments # ). Thank you for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

A minus sign or a special character isn't allowed in a variable name in Unix.

You may consider using BASH associative array for storing key and value together:

```
# declare an associative array
declare -A arr

# read file and populate the associative array
while IFS== read -r k v; do
   arr["$k"]="$v"
done < file

# check output of our array
declare -p arr
declare -A arr='([VarA]="/path/to/a" [VarC]="/path/to/c" [VarB]="/path/to/b" [VarD]="description of program" )'
```

Comment: Thank you. Although this is a bit more detailed than the example chepner detailed, I'm going to mark his as the answer as it is the one I used and I didn't need much more detail. Thank you though, appreciate the time and help.

Comment: Well the reason why I posted an answer as an alternative because you mentioned there can be minus signs and special chars before `=`. If that's the case then `declare "$name=$value"` won't work.

Answer (score -1):

What about `source my-file`? It won't work with spaces though, but will work for what you've shared. This is an example:

```
reut@reut-home:~$ cat src 
test=123
test2=abc/def
reut@reut-home:~$ echo $test $test2

reut@reut-home:~$ source src
reut@reut-home:~$ echo $test $test2
123 abc/def
```

Comment: its a possibility, but I ideally need a solution that will cater for spaces as there are a few entries which have them. I'll update my question to include VarD with spaces